# How to check running jobs in my android device?

Tags: android, job-scheduling

Context from documentation.

- Schedule a job to be executed.  Will replace any currently scheduled job with the same

  - ID with the new information in the {@link JobInfo}.  If a job with the given ID is currently
  - running, it will be stopped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your app, you call JobScheduler.getAllPendingJobs().  It will get all the pending jobs for your app.

If you mean across all apps, you can't.